# Float / Float = strange result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, floating-point

I have two values, one from user input and another from DB.

```
var userinput = form["someInput"];
var valuefromDB = GetValue(someNumber);

public float? GetValue(int id){
return (float?) db.table.where(p=> p.id == id).select(p=> p.Value).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

userinput have value "1" as string, while valuefromDB havevalue 0.001 as float.

so 1 / 0.001 = 1000

but my c# code give me 999.999939 as result;

```
var final = float.Parse(userinput) / valuefromDB
```

when i have "2" as user input value, result is correct, 2000...

Comment: This is a consequence of float precision.

Comment: Everyone programmer should understand floating point numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers

Comment: Do you need base 10 precision, or do you need base 2?

Answer (score 9):

That's because not all decimal numbers can be accurately represented in binary (which is [the representation that `float` uses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)). The solution is to format the result to the desired number of decimal places, which will cause it to be rounded and displayed "correctly" as a consequence.

**Update:** To format a `float` for display, take a look at [this MSDN reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) and [this page of examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/).

Comment: Can you give me simple c# example? :)

Answer (score 1):

For pure precision which is not provided by float use decimal instead.

See [What is the difference between Decimal, Float and Double in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c)